# Python check if input number is string

Tags: python

When I run the below code, it always returns `Number please` no matter what I enter. Why does this happen?

```
number = input("please type number: ")
if type(number) != int:
    print('Number please')
else:
    print('number')
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, this should work:

```
string = input()
if string.isalpha():
   print("It is a string. You are correct!")
elif string.isdigit():
   print("Please enter a string.")
else:
   print("Please enter a proper string.")
```

The `.isalpha` is used for checking if it's a string. The `.isdigit` is used for checking if it's a number.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: So `-3` is not an integer, and `?` is not a string?